# How can I determine which view is active?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a viewController, with 5 views and I want to initialize some stuff depending on the view so in the `viewDidLoad()`, I want to do a :

```
if self.view == view1 { // Stuff here }
if self.view == view2 do { // Stuff here }
```

But it's doesn't work. So how can I detect the active view?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called just once. by default `self.view` is the `firstResponder` unless you explicitly do something like `[view1 becomeFirstResponder]` but then your **if**-condition will work for only `view1`. did you think about this? also... `self.view` will be `self.view`, not `view1` or `view2` unless you do some weird stuff involving methods like `addSubView` & `removeFromSuperView`

Answer (score 0):

```
if([self.view1 isFirstResponder]){
//Do some nice stuff
}
```

You can do it with `isFirstResponder`